# Can NLP algorithm run on Force.com platform?

Tags: salesforce, force.com, salesforce-lightning

I have a Salesforce lightning application which uses AWS services to run NLP algorithm. Is there a way to move the algorithm to Force.com and run it without using Heroku and Einstein services.